# source() path relative to the current script directory?

Tags: r

In my main R script, I am doing `source("some/path/script1.R")`. This script includes another script in that directory:

```
source("script2.R")
...
```

Now, this will not work. The simplest solution is to use `source("some/path/script2.R")` in script1.R. But that's ugly, and not robust at all - it can break if directories `some/path` change. I want reasonable solution where script1.R includes script2.R irrespective of how `some/path` looks like.

#### Is there a reasonably simple way to specify `source()` path relative to the current script?

Comment: Using a R project or building a package with functions is a solution

Comment: what you mean with "using an R project"?

Comment: When you are in a R project, the working directory is the folder of your project (and will not change unless you change it). So you can use `getwd()` to get path and source by constructing path to your file

Comment: @Clemsang you probably imply using of Rstudio? I am using just plain R (Rgui on Windows).

Comment: Yes using RStudio.Please try `source("file.R", chdir = TRUE)` that shoud work

Comment: Please read https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/

Comment: @Clemsang wow, that's it, thanks!!! That should be an answer. Kent thanks too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

`source("file.R", chdir = TRUE)`

Comment: It does not work, since `file.R` has to be a path according to the documentation.

Comment: It is a relative path to current file that launch the commands here

Comment: It does not work for me